# special square character appearing in html on chrome only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm getting a square character rendering in html and displaying on chrome only. Is there a way I can stop this from rendering. It is appearing in the footer on this site: http://creative-testing.xyz/whaiawa/build-options/. I can't seem to remove it.

[image: here is the image]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<div class="fusion-row">
    <div class="fusion-columns fusion-columns-2 fusion-widget-area">
    <div class="fusion-column col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div id="text-3" class="fusion-footer-widget-column widget widget_text">
    <div class="textwidget"><img class="attachment-full aligncenter" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://creative-testing.xyz/whaiawa/wp-content/uploads/footer-logo.svg">
    <h3>027 228 6866<br/>sales@whaiawa.co.nz</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see this square character in Chrome. Can you upload some screenshot?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 58.0.3 and I don't see anything wrong. Have you tried clearing your cache and then refreshing the page?

Comment: It appears out of nowhere. I've attached a screen shot. Yes, cleared cache. I'll add the code also.

Comment: I see you are using wordpress. In your HTML or widget try cutting the content, then paste it in to notepad. If the square appears in notepad delete it. Then copy it from notepad and paste it back to your website. It could be a hidden character pasted from a word processor. On a side note, that auto scroll to the top is really annoying :P

Comment: @WizardCoder you're right. That square is there in your code @S Saffari

Answer (score 1):

That square is a character in your code. If you're using a CMS, you may not be able to see it. Have you tried deleting the phone number and writing it out again? I presume you copied and pasted it from a text editor before? If that doesn't work, let us know!